# How to import data as number rather than string from excel file in Drools workbench?

Tags: drools, kie-workbench

**First** question. As shown in Fig 6.16 in [6.5.3. How Decision Tables Work](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch06.html#d0e4948), when imported the rule excel file to workbench, 'age' in Column C is considered as a string, that is,

```
Person(age=="42")
```

How to make it as a number? So in the rule we can get

```
Person(age==42)
```

**Another** question, when rule tables put in multiple sheets, only the one in the first sheet is recognized. Is that expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a condition

```
CONDITION
Fact
age >
Test for age limit
42
```

the rule will contain

```
Fact(age > "42")
```

However, if you use

```
CONDITION
Fact
age > $param
Test for age limit
42
```

the rule will contain

```
Fact(age > 42)
```

But, normally, this should not matter and the outcome should be the same. Or can you provide an example where it is not?

The answer to another question can be found in the Drools documentation, section 6.5.4.1, Spreadsheet Structure, last paragraph.

Comment: You are so cool, Laune! As to your question, if I want to set age of a fact, it should be an number, right?

Then another question here, how can I **specify the type of number (int/float/double) in the sheet**? Since the setAge() method may accept only one of the three, it's kinda important.

Comment: In a setter call, on the RHS, it's Java, so setAge must use a parameter according to type. In the spreadsheet you can enter anything; rule generation and compilation will indicate an error if there's a mismatch. I guess you could do some checks with Excel macros, but I've never tried this.

Comment: Here I got a workaround: make the number to be float-point display in spreadsheet (for example, **40** is displayed as **40.00**), then it'll be interpreted as a double in the rule. But I still don't know how to make it as float in the rule.

Comment: Why do you think you need float? But you can use `age > $paramF`.

Comment: I want to pass the float number to a method whose parameter is float, such as setAge(float f).

Hmm, sorry for knowing little about JAVA.

It's great to get your replies. Thanks, Laune.

Comment: An int would be OK. - float as a method parameter should be avoided unless it is well motivated.